# Extjs makes hundreds of requests to ext-dev.js scripts

Tags: debugging, extjs, netbeans

My extjs application got extraordinarily slow from yesterday that I made some minor changes in my application and it makes 500 GET requests to ext-dev.js scripts now. Why is this happening and how can I revert it or fix it?

Comment: Perhaps you switched from `ext-all.js` to `ext.js`, which means that it does load every required component from its own file. Other than that, it's hard to say without more info. Don't you have source control?

Comment: no I didn't switch to ext.js. And yes I am using source and I undo all my changes but still having the same problem.

Comment: I'm getting this warning also, "Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience." not sure if they're related

Comment: Btw, ext-dev.js is the only resource I'm using.

Comment: it was happening only when I was debugging my java application, I run it now and there was no problem!

Answer (score 0):

I had so many break points in my IDE and that was the problem.